# why does text written to Canvas get darker when written twice to the same location?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

When text is written to the identical location more than once it gets darker. Why?

```
var txt = "The cat is on the mat";
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");   
ctx.font = "15px Lucida Sans Unicode";
ctx.fillText(txt,10,50);
ctx.fillText(txt,10,50);     // again
ctx.fillText(txt,10,100);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edges of text are anti-aliased, which means they are blended with the background. When you lay text on top of more text, it's blending with the anti-aliased edge of the text behind it, making it look aliased and larger (thus darker). Think two pieces of smoked glass set in front of each other.